# Invalid Argument Error

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

Im getting an error at the following URL:
http://www.greenmonkeypublicrelations.com/citypads/apartments/the-ivinghoe-2-bedroom-1-bathroom-apartment/

The purpose here is to identify if the post has children, if it has children, to list the terms of those children and echo the permalink to the post as the href and echo the term title as the text to show. Also if the post is a child, then to get the parent post and list the same to show the links on both levels. 
Heres my code:

```
<?php 
        if( has_children() ){
            $postid = get_the_ID(); 
            $args = array(
                'post_parent' => $postid,
                'post_type'   => 'any', 
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'post_status' => 'any' 
            ); 
            $children_array = get_children( $args, OBJECT );
            foreach ($children_array as $child) {
                $terms = get_the_terms( $child->ID, 'Apartment_type' );
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    echo '<a href="' . $child->guid . '">' . $term->name . '</a><br/>';
                }
            }       
        } elseif (!has_children()) {
            if ( wp_get_post_parent_id( get_the_id() ) ){
                $postid = wp_get_post_parent_id( get_the_id() );    
                $args = array(
                    'post_parent' => $postid,
                    'post_type'   => 'any', 
                    'numberposts' => -1,
                    'post_status' => 'any' 
                ); 
                $children_array = get_children( $args, OBJECT );
                foreach ($children_array as $child) {
                    $terms = get_the_terms( $child->ID, 'Apartment_type' );
                    foreach ($terms as $term) {
                        echo '<a href="' . $child->guid . '">' . $term->name . '</a><br/>';
                    }
                }
            }                   
        } elseif( ( !has_children() ) && (!get_post_ancestors( $post->ID ))) { 
            echo 'on its own';  
        } ?>
```

Comment: what is the return value of get_children( $args, OBJECT ); if it not has children? an empty array or false or...?

Comment: Would you like to see the var_dump($children_array)?

Comment: yes, and the get_the_terms( $child->ID, 'Apartment_type' ); i think one of them is not an array

Comment: Current view is var_dump($children_array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you expect `$children_array` or `$terms` are always `arrays`. foreach expects an array, so if the `$children_array` or `$terms` have the value (i.e.) `false` you'll get this error.

Can you try this:

```
<?php
if( has_children() ){
    $postid = get_the_ID();
    $args = array(
        'post_parent' => $postid,
        'post_type'   => 'any',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'any'
    );
    $children_array = get_children( $args, OBJECT );
    if( is_array( $children_array ) ) {
        foreach ($children_array as $child) {
            $terms = get_the_terms( $child->ID, 'Apartment_type' );
            if( is_array( $terms ) ) {
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    echo '<a href="' . $child->guid . '">' . $term->name . '</a><br/>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
} elseif (!has_children()) {
    if ( wp_get_post_parent_id( get_the_id() ) ){
        $postid = wp_get_post_parent_id( get_the_id() );
        $args = array(
            'post_parent' => $postid,
            'post_type'   => 'any',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'any'
        );
        $children_array = get_children( $args, OBJECT );
        if( is_array( $children_array ) ) {
            foreach ($children_array as $child) {
                $terms = get_the_terms( $child->ID, 'Apartment_type' );
                if( is_array( $terms ) ) {
                    foreach ($terms as $term) {
                        echo '<a href="' . $child->guid . '">' . $term->name . '</a><br/>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} elseif( ( !has_children() ) && (!get_post_ancestors( $post->ID ))) {
    echo 'on its own';
} ?>
```

Comment: That seems to have solved it, got a new error regarding something else but not related. 
What was the issue?

Comment: The issue is that you expect children_array or terms are always arrays. Foreach expects an array, so if the children_array or terms have the value (i.e.) false you'll get this error